# Failed to install Truffle

Tags: truffle

This message shows up when I try to install truffle

```
npm install -g truffle
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/janinebarnard/.npm/_logs/2018-
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this command `sudo npm install -g truffle`, installation is failing because of an issue related to administrator permission

Comment: I tried that as well put it gives me now password with a key at the end.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problema and solve it with **chmod 777** in all files

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue on *npm@6.14.11*, upgrading *npm* to the latest version resolve the issue:

```bash
npm install -g npm@latest
sudo npm install truffle -g
```